# Remove and reset Static Object

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I am working on an app that has a static countdown running. It needs to be static since the object itself needs to be accessed from different classes. 
But after redoing this bit of code for a while:

```
timer.Stop();
timer.Dispose();
timer.Enabled = false;
timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 10;
timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

My app becomes extremely slow. I believe that maybe I am not disposing the timer object right and therefore creating many objects in the ram. Evneutally, after many times of this code, the app fails.

Am I disposing the object right before setting it up again (with the new keyword)? Or am I missing something vital?

Thank you!

It is:

```
public static System.Timers.Timer timer;
```

Well the reason why this is static, is because in my activity in my app there is also a recyler view integrated. And when I click on an item in my recycler view i need to manipulate the timer from outside the recycler view but inside the activity as well. If the timer is not public static I would have to intstantiate another object of that timer but this is not affecting the currently running timer. So maybe I got this all wrong? Is there a third option? Thank you!

Comment: "It needs to be static since the object itself needs to be accessed from different classes" That doesn´t mean it has to be static. It does only mean there is no *instance* of your class. Anyway I agree rory, there is no static here.

Comment: Maybe you don't unsubscribe? timer.Elapsed -= OnTimedEvent;

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be static as others have mentioned, you can use a singleton with dependency injection or some factory method. Regardless, if you want to ensure proper disposal it may be easier to simply wrap it in a 'using' block.

Comment: Leaving the AutoReset property set to true with such short intervals is a very bad idea.  Hilarious things happen when the event handler takes more than 10 msec.  Also look in the Output window for a possible storm of exceptions.

Comment: Why are you stopping it at all and creating new ones? This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: Disposing does not unsubscribe events, see my comment above.

Comment: Use memory profile to detect leak. But my best guess it is event.

Comment: Can you talk us through why you need to remove and reset the timer? Why not keep using the one, single timer?

Comment: @mjwills well basically, the timer varaible didnt have a "reset" property. So instead of overriding my timer class i just reinstantiated the object so that it would technically be reset. anyway: it turned out that just stopping and starting the timer resets the timer itself. so the property wasnt needed and the problem is totally solved. thank you a lot. if you post as answer, I will accept and upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these kinds of scenarios, your best bet is to **reuse** the existing timer rather than dispose old ones and create new ones. *This saves you having to worry about unsubscribing event handlers etc.*

I suspect you want to [Stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.stop?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.start?view=netframework-4.7.2) it instead.